# How to pass a template type as parameter to non-template function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following problem with my function template. If I have a function template like this, where `T` can be of either `ClassA` or `ClassB`:

```
template<typename T, bool flag>
void function(T& someT){
    if(flag){    /*If 'flag' is true, 'someT' MUST be of type ClassA*/
        nonTemplateFunction1(someT);
    }
    else{    /*Else 'someT' must be of type ClassB*/
        nonTemplateFunction2(someT);
    }
}
```

And in some other File I have

```
void nonTemplateFunction1(ClassA& a){...}
```

and in yet another file I have

```
void nonTemplateFunction2(ClassB& b){...}
```

Now if I call my function template, I get an error at compiling:

> error: no matching member function for call to 'nonTemplateFunction2'

I guess that is because the compiler tests the call to `nonTemplateFunction2` with `ClassA` as parameter for example. But this can never happen (at least I, the programmer, take care of this). How can i get my program to compile? What are possible solutions?

**EDIT:** A more precise error:

> ./tabledata.hh:371:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'bulk_insert'
>                                               bi.bulk_insert(bl, aRel_Vec[j]);
>
> ../pax/bulk_insert_pax.hh:21:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'value_type' (aka 'NSM_Relation') to 'PAX_Relation &' for 2nd argument
>                       void bulk_insert(const BulkLoader& aBulkLoader, PAX_Relation& aRelation);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing compile time decisions with runtime decisions. Compiler does know the type of `someT`, yes, but it does not delete the `if` branch. Basically after processing, it looks like this:

```
void function(ClassA& someT){
    if(true){
        nonTemplateFunction1(someT);
    }
    // branch will be optimized away, but still 
    // exists
    else{
        // so this is still erroneous code, even though it never runs
        nonTemplateFunction2(someT);
    }
}
```

So either see a way to remove unwanted branch during preprocesing, or use pointer instead of reference or refactor your function. I'm not sure what the options are, I'm not good with templates, but maybe you can pass some flag to `#ifdef`?

Comment: Hm, looks like I have to pass a pointer to my T then. Not my favorite solution but it should work

Comment: @N.Weber I think that's the fastest option, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you'll be able to use `if constexpr` to do that (your example code as-is):

```
class ClassA{};
class ClassB{};

void nonTemplateFunction1(ClassA&){}
void nonTemplateFunction2(ClassB&){}

template<typename T, bool flag>
void function(T& someT){
    if constexpr (flag){
        nonTemplateFunction1(someT);
    }
    else{
        nonTemplateFunction2(someT);
    }
}

int main() {
    ClassA a;
    function<ClassA, true>(a);
}
```

See it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/z23S1EN9ZT5fYHRV).

---

In C++11/14 you can rely on sfinae. It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

class ClassA{};
class ClassB{};

void nonTemplateFunction1(ClassA&){}
void nonTemplateFunction2(ClassB&){}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, ClassA>::value>
function(T& someT){
    nonTemplateFunction1(someT);
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, ClassB>::value>
function(T& someT){
    nonTemplateFunction2(someT);
}

int main() {
    ClassA a;
    function(a);
}
```

You can also use this if you prefer and don't want to be explicit about the types:

```
template<typename T>
auto function(T& someT)
-> decltype(nonTemplateFunction1(someT), void()) {
    nonTemplateFunction1(someT);
}

template<typename T>
auto function(T& someT)
-> decltype(nonTemplateFunction2(someT), void()) {
    nonTemplateFunction2(someT);
}
```