# Use variable of generic template type as parameter to another function

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use template type to simulate genericity in C++
I have a function that goes like this

```
template <typename ElementType1>
void myFile::myFunc() {
     ElementType1 val = Strain() //
  
     loadNewValue(val); // this is where the problem is , "impossible to convert type ElementType1 to type Strain"
```

and now the loadNewValue method :

```
void myFile::loadNewValue(Strain strain) {
    //DoSomething;
}
```

and how I call my myFunc function

```
myFunc<Strain>();
```

and struct Strain:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Strain_H
#define Strain_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Strain {
    int64_t ID;
    
};

#endif // Strain
```

I tried to simplify because my example is way bigger

My problem is that I can't compile this code, because the compiler expects to be able to convert my generic type "ElementType1" into "Strain" because I use it as a parameter for my loadNewValue function

What I expected was that the type of ElementType1 was known during runtime, and since at runtime it will correctly be Strain (which I verified with a `cout` of the type when commenting `loadNewValue), it would just fill the parameter.

I tried to cast val to "Strain" but I get the same error, since compiler doesn't know how to compile ElementType1 to Strain.

I think I must have a missconception of what generic template name do, since I thought they were evaluated at runtime after function call, not compile time

Thanks for your help

Comment: please try to create a [mcve]. A mre is not just a fragment of the actual code, but it is code that can be compiled to get the same error

Comment: for example "// this is a function from another library (HD.... " rather than posting incomplete code and describing how the actual code looks like you can simply post code: `?? funcStore() { return {}; }` , I Had to put `??` because i dont know what it returns

Comment: in the code you posted here `val` is a `Strain`, `loadNewValue` takes a `Strain`, no problem

Comment: To be able to compile my code you'd need to install several C++ library because of the line ElementType1 val = funcStore(), I have no idea how this function works behind the scene, but it uses pointer to automaticly fill the parameter of my template type.

My question is more about why is my compiler expecting my generic template type to be of "Strain" type at compile time while I thought template time were checked at run time, and how to avoid this problem

Comment: "To be able to compile my code you'd need to install several C++ ... " no i dont. You just have to provide an example that does not need those libraries. The error is not caused by the libraries, so you can provide an example that does not include those libraries. The code you did post does not have the issue you describe

Comment: val is of Strain type during runtime yes, but my problem is I can't compile, because MVS expect ElementType1 to be of type "Strain" during compilation

Comment: in `myFunc<Strain>` the `ElementType1` is `Strain`. At compile time.

Comment: @SparklingMarcel Replace funcStore by your own function that returns an object of a dummy type for example and try to reproduce.
By the way, does funcStore returns a plain object, some reference,...?

Comment: Error C2664 : impossible to convert argument 1 of type 'ElementType1' to 'Strain' 268 
If I print val during runtime; it correctly prints "Strain", but if I had my if statement with the 2 function call, I get the above error message

Comment: in the code you posted `ElementType1` is not a type, its just the name of a tempalte argument, and in the only instantiation you are using `ElementType1` is `Strain`. "cannot convert ElementType1 to Strain" makes no sense for this code

Comment: btw `myFunc<Strain>("Strain");`  does not match `if(type=="STRAIN")`. And my guess is that `loadNewValue(val);` expects that `val` is `Strain` while `loadNewValueNotStrain(val);` expects that `val` is something else. Though, thats just guessing. YOu need to tell us what those functions are. And no, we do not need to see the actual library functions. Any dummy function with same signature that you can write yourself will probably suffice

Comment: Well, as you see my compiler is considering during compilation that ElementType1 is of type ElementType1. Btw my problem is almost the same as this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753536/how-to-pass-a-template-type-as-parameter-to-non-template-function

but it was in 2017 and there was no solution found, so I hoped in 8 years span there was an alternative.

Comment: i can see that the code you posted here is not the code that produces the error message you refer to. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: HDFql::variableTransientRegister(&val);
            std::string query = "SELECT FROM /DATASET INTO MEMORY 0";
          HDFql::execute(query.c_str());

That's how "val" variable is constructed, I have no idea how this function works behind the scene, all I know is that it tries to fill whatever parameter my object I registered has, and if my object is not exactly the same as the expected dataset, it still fills it with bad values.

whatever happens in this function, cout << typeid(val).name() << endl; actually prints "Strain" if my template is Strain and something else otherwise

Comment: why you say "there was no solution found" ?!? The accepted answer explains the conceptual problem in the code quite well and the other answer explains how to use `constexpr if`

Comment: the solution explicitly says ". I'm not sure what the options are, I'm not good with templates, but maybe you can pass some flag to #ifdef?"

2nd solution doesn't correspond to my problem since his was the evaluation of the boolean as template type

Comment: compiles here : https://godbolt.org/z/vbjdv7jGo. YOur actual code is different. What is different only you know

Comment: The only difference in my code is that ElementType1 val is aumatically filled with the function I posted above, but that's at runtime, not compiletime

btw, if you wanna, just replace ElementType1 val = someFunc() by 
ElementType1 val = Strain() (which isn't what would happen, but anyway it doesn't change the problem)

The error remains the same, simply because compiler thinks ElementType1 is of type ElementType1 not Strain()
I'm using MVS2019

Comment: `myFunc<Strain>("String")` instantiates the function template at compile time with `Strain` for `ElementType1`. This does not happen at runtime. I can only repeat, your code with the problem is different from the code you posted here. The code you posted here does not have the issue. To get help with broken code you should try to create a [mcve]

Comment: I posted a minimal reproductible example, that causes exactly the same error by editing my post

Comment: what you posted is not a minimal reproducible example. It produces compiler errors (a lot) but not the one you talk about. https://godbolt.org/z/1TYPKoG1a

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/M41Wdje97

Comment: Your website is not working, it's only showing a blank page

Comment: you seem to misunderstand how templates work. In `myFunc<Strain>()` the `ElementTye1` is `Strain`. It cannot be something else

Comment: The problem seems to come from the configuration of the MVS project, I tried to run the same minimal example in 2 project, got different outcome, example :
template <typename ElementType1>
void myFunc() {
    ElementType1 val = Strain();
}
and then
int main()
{
    myFunc<Strain>();
   
    return 0;
}

returns "cannot convert Strain to ElementType1" but only in one of my project

Comment: this looks like an example that does rely on third party libraries. I am afraid the quesiton here is a train wreck. I would suggest to open a new quesiton with this simpler example, just make sure to make it complete and include all the code in the question together with the information on your msvc configuration

Comment: Yes, I'll try to find myself first what's happening configuration wise, and then maybe do another post, sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 1):

> My question is more about why is my compiler expecting my generic template type to be of "Strain" type at compile time while I thought template time were checked at run time, and how to avoid this problem

Template is all done at compile time.
With regular `if` all branches should be valid.
With `if constexpr`, the "wrong" branches are not instantiated.

So you might possibly do:

```
template <typename ElementType1>
void myFile::myFunc()
{
    ElementType1 val = funcStore() // this is a function from another library (HDFql) that automaticly "fill" val argument, this works
    if (std::is_same_v<Strain, type>) {
        loadNewValue(val);
    } else {
        loadNewValueNotStrain(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, sadly even without the if branching (so only with loadNewValue) the problem remains the same

Comment: If you drop template and do `STrain train; loadNewValue(train);`. Do you have issue?

Comment: Then I don't get the problem anymore.
But as stated above in a comment, I know think the problem comes from MVS2019 configuration, because the same example (last comment above) in both project don't produce the same outcome :/